# Оптимальное значение TTL (Time to Live)?

Tags: сеть, tcp, tcp-ip

Считается, что теорию 6-ти рукопожатий можно сравнить с `TTL=~45`. Т.е, значение `45` вполне достаточно для доставки пакета любому маршрутизатору в сети.

- Использовать значение `TTL=10` - не совсем правильно, и пакет может не дойти.
- Использовать значение `TTL=255` - смысла нет.

Вопрос: `TTL=45` - гарантирует, что пакет будет доставлен, верно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `TTL=45` - гарантирует, что пакет будет доставлен, верно?

В теории — конечно нет, ни каких гарантий. Любой админ может заскучать длинным зимним вечером и поставить 46 маршрутизаторов в ряд или настроить один, чтобы он уменьшал TTL сразу на 32. Само собой через них такой пакет уже не пройдёт.

В реальных условиях — опять же, ни каких гарантий. Даже значения по умолчанию (64 или 128) не дают гарантий на этот счёт. Но вариант, что количество hop'ов окажется больше, — крайне маловероятен. Конечно, всё это подразумевая, что исследователи назвавшие число `45` действительно правы, а не взяли его с потолка.

Comment: Ответу не хватает доказательств и аргументации фактами. Если мы подставим 4 или 450 вместо 45 в текст объяснения ответа, то оно никак не изменится по сути ..

Comment: @Kromster, число `45`, было названо OP'ом... источника, откуда он его взял у меня нет. Моя позиция в том, что каким бы TTL ни было, *гарантий*, что цепочка маршрутизаторов не окажется длиннее **ни кто дать не может**, если кто-то найдёт подтверждение/опровержение этому в нормативной документации — добавлю; так что есть только разумные практические значения. `4` — очевидно мало для типового использования, не думаю, что это нужно пояснять, а `450` в 1 байт запихнуть сложно... Но большие значения (условно говоря `128+`) создадут лишний оверхед при зацикливании маршрутов.

Comment: TL;DR: *"Никаких гарантий нет. Надеемся что тот кто назвал 45 знал что говорит."*

Comment: @Kromster, секция tl;dr жирновато для ответа из пары коротеньких абзацев =)